# Unloaded winmmbase.dll visual studio 2015

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I'm trying to build some openCV projects with visual c++ 2015 using openCV 3.1.0
But I'm still getting the same error with some projects.

'ConsoleApplication4.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'

***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

The thread 0x1e90 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x1e78 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x620 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[4824] ConsoleApplication4.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

this is the related code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";

int main(void)
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat  frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); return -1; };
    if (!eyes_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n"); return -1; };

    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture.open(-1);
    if (!capture.isOpened()) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n");          return -1; }

    while (capture.read(frame))
    {
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }

        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay(frame);

        int c = waitKey(10);
        if ((char)c == 27) { break; } // escape
    }  
return 0;
}


void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
{
std::vector<Rect> faces;
Mat frame_gray;

cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);


face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height / 2);
    ellipse(frame, center, Size(faces[i].width / 2, faces[i].height / 2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]);
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;


    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    for (size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++)
    {
        Point eye_center(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width / 2, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height / 2);
        int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25);
        circle(frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);
    }
}

imshow(window_name, frame);
}
```

Is there any solution?
thanks.

Comment: can you try to use `capture.open(0);` (and try 1, 2, 3 etc too) instead of `capture.open(-1);`? What kind of devices are connected to your machine?

Comment: Thanks Micka. It worked with capture.open(0) !
I'm using a usb webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using prebuilt libraries? Because they are only for version VC11(Visual Studio 2012) and VC12 (Visual Studio 2013). To use OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015 you need to compile your own libraries with CMake. Look [HERE](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) for detailed instructions

Answer (score 1):

You are using `capture.open(-1)`. I'm not sure whether this is allowed at all (intention is to open the "default" device?). In addition, sometimes multiple devices are installed and sometimes, drivers aren't correct.

Please try to choose your device directly:

```
capture.open(0); // or capture.open(1 / 2 / 3 / 4 ...);
```

If you need more information about which devices are attached, you might need to switch to a better video device library like `VideoInput` http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/

Answer (score 0):

Read again openCV 3.1.0 has prebuild Visual Studio 2015 libs. Fist of all. The face_cascade.detectMultiScale in my case have some bugs in 3.1. I need to use release instead of debug mode to get right output. I dont know why. Problem is somewhere else. Try empty project VS 2015 with right settings instead of console application.